# Is there anyway to send screenshot of a website to email in Kivy?

Tags: android, kivy

I am developing an app that need to send screenshot of any webpage that is opening in browser on android device to email. Is it possible?

I am doing like this:

I will open the website:

```
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
def data(req):
req = UrlRequest('http://html5demos.com/geo)
```

Now I want to send this screen to email. I do not care if the site opens in backgroud. All I need is to send the screenshot to email. Is is possible with Kivy?

Comment: You need to use an smtp library to send e-mails. For Python there is smtplib.Search it and if you want to compile your project dont forget to add to ./distribute.sh script the "openssl" module. Example on linux terminal : $ ./distribute.sh -m "openssl kivy".

Comment: I don't have problem in sending mail. I have problem in taking screenshot.

Comment: then you definitely need to access camera utilities via kivy. To be honest i have never tried it but it seems interesting your idea. have a look at this i hope it might help http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.camera.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of doing that in Kivy. Kivy is for displaying UI, not for rendering webpage.
I guess in your case, you would need to open an external webbrowser, and capture the android screen, but that's outside the Kivy's scope.